# Prevent a player from holding attack button using timers in Unity (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, timer, 2d

I am a pretty amateur dev trying to create a simple runner style game to help me learn unity. In the runner, I want the player to have the option to attack enemies instead of simply avoid them. So, in the code below if you press "A", the player "smacks," which changes the sprite to the attack sprite. However, if you hold "A", the player remains in the attack animation.

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && didWeckySmack == false)
        {
            spriteRenderer.sprite = weckySmack;
            smackTimer = smackTimer + Time.deltaTime;
            if (smackTimer >= timeToSmack)
            {
                didWeckySmack = true;
                Debug.Log("Stop smacking!");
                Debug.Log(smackTimer);
            }
            
            
        }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A) || didWeckySmack == true)
        {
            spriteRenderer.sprite = weckyRun;
            smackTimer = 0;
            didWeckySmack = false;
        }
```

I've tried using GetKeyDown/GetKeyUp instead of GetKey as well as using timers and a boolean value, and my Debug lines even show up in the console, but my player still stays in the attack sprite. I would like for after x time of holding the key for the player to return to the default sprite and be required to press the attack key again to return to the attack sprite. I don't mind if the player can spam the key as I plan to implement other gameplay that would make spamming the attack key ineffective. Help?

I was able to solve the issue but thought I'd leave the post up so others could see the solution. Here is what I did:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && didWeckySmack == false)
        {
            spriteRenderer.sprite = weckySmack;
            smackTimer = smackTimer + Time.deltaTime;
                
        }

        if (didWeckySmack == true)
        {
            spriteRenderer.sprite = weckyRun;
        }

        if (smackTimer >= timeToSmack)
        {
            didWeckySmack = true;
            Debug.Log("Stop smacking!");
            Debug.Log(smackTimer);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A))
        {
            spriteRenderer.sprite = weckyRun;
            smackTimer = 0;
            didWeckySmack = false;
        }
```